# I've the issue with Suspending system in Ubuntu 16.04LTS

Tags: suspend

I use standard corporation HW DELL Latitude-E5570 and i had no this issue before.

I'm not sure if this can be relate with auto purging unused packages (sudo apt-get autoremove) due low space in /boot partition.
Actually I've this in my syslog after susspending:

```
Jun 25 11:09:37 ***-Latitude-E5570 systemd[1]: Reached target Sleep.
Jun 25 11:09:37 ***-Latitude-E5570 systemd[1]: Starting Suspend...
Jun 25 11:09:37 ***-Latitude-E5570 systemd-sleep[10122]: Failed to connect to non-global ctrl_ifname: (nil)  error: No such file or directory
Jun 25 11:09:37 ***-Latitude-E5570 systemd-sleep[10123]: /lib/systemd/system-sleep/wpasupplicant failed with error code 255.
Jun 25 11:09:37 ***-Latitude-E5570 systemd-sleep[10122]: Suspending system...
Jun 25 11:18:03 ***-Latitude-E5570 rsyslogd: [origin software="rsyslogd" swVersion="8.16.0" x-pid="1075" x-info="http://www.rsyslog.com"] start
```

I read some threads pointing to graphical driver problems, but I didn't touch this before problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ cat /lib/systemd/system-sleep/wpasupplicant
#!/bin/sh
set -e

if [ "$2" = "suspend" ] || [ "$2" = "hybrid-sleep" ]; then
    case "$1" in
        pre) /sbin/wpa_cli suspend ;;
        post) /sbin/wpa_cli resume ;;
    esac
fi
```

You have a problem with `/sbin/wpa_cli`, which is part of the `wpasupplicant` package.